# XPS viewer similar to Adobe PDF viewer

Tags: documents

Is there a way to open Microsoft XPS documents on Android, similar to the way Adobe PDF documents have "Adobe Reader for Android"? I took a look in the Market but I didn't find anything.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm looking for an XPS reader too.  Two points.  First, Google Docs Viewer supports .XPS files ([Getting to know the Google Docs Viewer](http://docs.google.com/support/bin/answer.py?hl=en&answer=1189935)) but Google Docs Mobile Viewer ***does not***, per my experience and this support page ([Viewing files from within Google Docs](http://www.google.com/support/mobile/bin/answer.py?hl=en&answer=184030)).  I spent time trying because [this cached page](http://webcache.googleusercontent.com/search?q=cache%3aJhILjDpwCDYJ%3awww.onlinereviewtoday.com/2010/06/google-docs-mobile-viewer-for-android-iphone-ipad-has-been-released.html%20android%20xps%20viewer&cd=7&hl=en&ct=clnk&gl=us&client=firefox-a&source=www.google.com)'s article title is

> Google Docs Mobile Viewer for Android, iPhone, iPad has Been Released

and has this list of tags that made me think I'd found a solution.

> Article Tags:xps Android, xps viewer android, android xps, 
>   xps viewer for android, android xps viewer, android xps reader, 
>   XPS reader android

Second, perhaps if enough people show interest there will be an XPS Viewer available from the Android Market.  I added to the [Android Market XPS Viewer Feature Request thread](http://www.google.com/support/forum/p/Android+Market/thread?tid=4078759a00cd1577&hl=en&fid=4078759a00cd15770004a6d84161291d).

Comment: this is no longer true, see the other answers

Answer (score 1):

I use [Documento - office viewer](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.igates.office&hl=en) to open XPS files.

Answer (score 1):

There's an app called [EBookDroid](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=org.ebookdroid)

Comment: Worth noting: this is open-source (always nice to be able to see what the apps you are installing are doing on your device)

Comment: No longer an open source app!

Answer (score 0):

[Docs Viewer](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.meltingsource.DocsViewer&hl=en) is a free app on the Play Store that you can use to view XPS files and other documents in a big number of formats on your Android devices.

Answer (score 0):

mupdf supports viewing XPS and is free / opensource:

https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.artifex.mupdf.viewer.app